# Duplicate line and replace string with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have an XML file that contains several items.

Each item contains a line like this:

```
<path>./filename.zip</path>
```

For each item I need to add another line below like this:

```
<manual><./media/manuals/filename.pdf></manual>
```

So I need to duplicate each <path> line and replace with <manual>.
filename is windows

The final result would be like this:

```
<path>./filename.zip</path>
<manual><./media/manuals/filename.pdf></manual>
```

I should be able to do this using regular expressions in notepad++. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only for zip files?

Comment: What do you mean by "filename is windows"? NPP is used in Windows? But the filepath has `/` separators. Also, is it an XML? Then use an XSL, you can use XSLT with NPP, too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Find: `<path>\.(.*?)\.\w+</path>`
Replace: `\0\r\n<manual>./media/manuals/\1.pdf</manual>`

fyi group zero is the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

find: `(<path>)(\.{0,2}\/)(.*?)(\.zip<\/path>)`

replace: `\1\2\3.zip<\/path>\r\n    <manual>.\/media\/manuals\/\3.pdf<\/manual>`

Comment: Why capture hardcoded input?

Comment: @CAustin I often do that when I use case insensitive searches and I want to preserve the case of the input text.